# plotly theme change issue

Tags: django, plotly, plotly-dash, django-plotly-dash

I am using Plotly Python in my Django application. I have two themes in my web app dark and light.
If a light theme is selected chart background is white and for a dark theme, the chart background is set black. That is done using the following code in the dark_theme_template and light_theme_template respectively.

The issue I am getting is when one user changes the theme it affects the other user’s chart when the other user refreshes or callback is hit.

## dark theme template

```
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.graph_objs import Layout
import plotly.graph_objects as go

dark_template_layout = Layout(
    paper_bgcolor="black",
    plot_bgcolor="black",
    # other dark theme settings ...
)


dark_template = go.layout.Template()
dark_template.layout = dark_template_layout
```

## light theme template

```
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.graph_objs import Layout
import plotly.graph_objects as go

white_template_layout = Layout(
    paper_bgcolor="white",
    plot_bgcolor="white",
    # further light theme settings ...
)


white_template = go.layout.Template()
white_template.layout = white_template_layout
```

setting the templates and setting the dark theme as the default

```
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.graph_objs import Layout
import plotly.graph_objects as go


from apps.dashboards.themes.dark_theme import dark_template
from apps.dashboards.themes.white_theme import white_template


pio.templates["white_template"] = white_template
pio.templates["dark_template"] = dark_template

pio.templates.default = "dark_template"
```

when user change the theme this view is called

```
class ChangeTheme(View):
    def post(self, request):
        response = {}
        try:
            light_mode = True if request.POST.get("light_mode") == "true" else False
            if light_mode:
                request.session["light_mode"] = True
                request.session.save()

                pio.templates.default = "white_template"

            else:
                request.session["light_mode"] = False
                request.session.save()
                
                pio.templates.default = "dark_template"

        except Exception as error:

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
```

I know pio.template.default = '' is causing the issue, as it is set globally across application. So when another user changes the theme it changes for all other users on the system.

What’s the recommended best practice to ensure that each user’s theme preference is independent of others, maintaining separate themes for different users without global interference? How can I refactor my code to achieve this?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know `pio.template.default = ''` is causing the issue, as it is set globally across application.

True: it means any change to it affects all users, regardless of their individual theme preferences.

A recommended best practice would be to *not* changing the global defaults, but instead to dynamically set the template for each chart based on the user's theme preference when rendering the chart.

Store each user's theme preference in their session or a profile model in the database.
When rendering a chart for a user, fetch their theme preference and apply the appropriate theme.

Here, I will use the session, as mentioned in [`GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash` issue 67](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/issues/67), and in [`GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/demo/demo/views.py`](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/blob/008cee19436cd6e9997bd6901a2858ef91feb99d/demo/demo/views.py#L12-L19)

First, to update the `ChangeTheme` view to just store the user's preference and not modify the global setting:

```py
class ChangeTheme(View):
    def post(self, request):
        response = {}
        try:
            light_mode = True if request.POST.get("light_mode") == "true" else False
            request.session["light_mode"] = light_mode
            request.session.save()

        except Exception as error:
            # handle error

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
```

Then you dynamically apply the theme when rendering a chart.
Let's assume, for instance, that you have a function/view `render_chart` that creates and returns a chart. Update this function to use the user-specific template:

```py
def render_chart(request):

    # Retrieve user's theme preference
    light_mode = request.session.get("light_mode", False)
    
    # Create chart
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    # Based on the user preference, apply the correct theme
    if light_mode:
        fig.update_layout(template="white_template")
    else:
        fig.update_layout(template="dark_template")

    # rest of the chart creation process
    
    return fig
```

Now, even if multiple users change their themes simultaneously, they will not interfere with each other's chart themes, as the theme is applied at the time of chart rendering and is user-specific.